# image attachment in mail with rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Here i need to attach one image with mail, the passing image like this

```
**imageurl** = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=%22hai%22&choe=UTF-8"

class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default :from => "mail@example.com"

 def welcome_email(**imageurl**,bname,mailid)
  **attachments['image.png'] = File.read(imageURL)**
  mail(:to => mailid,
  :subject => "Code for "+bname+"",
  :body => "code for bname" )
  end
 end
end
```

here i got some attachment error. Have any changes in this attachment?

thanks

Comment: The edits you are doing on your questions are not going to help you; they are not substantive improvements,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have a URL i.e a string which File.read cannot read.

```
require 'open-uri'
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(image_url,bname,mailid)
    attachments['image.png'] = open(URI.parse(image_url))
    ...
  end
end
```

The above should do the trick i think.

Comment: yes this will send one mail with attachment of image.png. But when i open or download that image, that is empty.?

Comment: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=%22hai%22&choe=UTF-8, Have any issues to open this from URI.parse()?

Comment: Use your Rails console. open the console and type in "require open-uri" then "URI.parse('google chart url')" and ensure you get a URI object. then do "s = open(_)" to ensure you can download the image as intended. if you dont get an imageish string there is something wrong. break down the steps and debug.

Comment: when i use like this
require "open-uri"
 => true 

URI.parse('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=5&choe=UTF-8')
 => #<URI::HTTPS:0xb5bf9b8 URL:https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=5&choe=UTF-8> 

 s = open('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=5&choe=UTF-8')
 => #<StringIO:0xb4f3ebc> 

have any issues with this URL?

Comment: Great! you got StringIO object! This means you are able to fetch something from the remote URL. StringIO is good! Now you can do .to_s on this object to see what it contains, or even do .content_type on it  to see what else it's got!

Comment: s.content_type
 => "image/png" 
can you check that image url, how to download the content from that url and sure it's in memory first?

Comment: The open command is downloading the content from the remote server and giving you a StringIO object already! So the download is already happening! :) You need to debug your program afterwards. put a debugger after the line where you set the attachment to see what is being stored within. Can you download the content using open uri, save it to a file and open that png file in an editor/browser?

Comment: lots of time i have tried that to download the image from this url, but i couldn't do that from this link https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=5&choe=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'open-uri'
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(image_url,bname,mailid)
    mail.attachments[image.png] = { :mime_type => type*, :content => open(URI.parse(image_url)}
    ...
  end
end
```

where type* is the type of attached file in your case it will be('image/png')

Comment: Again this will send one mail with attachment of image.png. But when i open or download that image, that is empty.?
def welcome_email(imageURL,branchNAME,mailID)
    
   encoded_content = open(URI.parse(imageURL))
   attachments['QR.png'] = { :mime_type => "image/png",
                                 
                                 :content => encoded_content}
    mail(:to => mailID,
    :subject => "QR from "+branchNAME+"",
    :body => "QR for the branch "+branchNAME+"")
  end
end